# Convert mouse coordinates from one window size to fit into another window size

Tags: javascript, html

Imagine two different windows with the same page loaded but different sizes. I want to pass the mouse coordinates from one window to the second window in order to point to the same location in both page.

How can I convert the mouse coordinates of the first window to fit in the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
otherMouseX = thisMouseX / thisWindowWidth * otherWindowWidth
```

and the same for mouse y